# how to get exact record using datareader

Tags: query-string

Can you please correct this code so that i can get particular companyName corresponding to the seekerID when i select the particular seekerID ... Pls its urgent.

while (reader.Read())
               {
                   if (lblseekerID.Text != Request.QueryString["seekerID"])
                  {
                      //if it is a text box
                       txtAdminCompany.Text = "wrong";

```
               }
               else
              {
                  //txtAdminCompany.Text = reader.["companyName"].ToString();
                   txtAdminCompany.Text=reader.IsDBNull(reader.GetOrdinal("companyName"))? null: reader["companyName"].ToString();
               }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
reader["companyName"]
```

instead.

Also, without seeing the db query that precedes your code, I suspect your SQL query may be the root of the problem. You should be doing something like:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE seekerID = " + seekID.ToString(); // cmd = SqlCommand object
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thnx a lot for ur reply.. actually my query is like this.      cmd.commandtext ="select * from tblSeeker c,tblLogin a where a.cus_logID =c.cus_logID" and i need not only company , i need all the details for the particular id

Comment: If you need other column values from the same query then you can just repeat the same 'reader[COLUMN_NAME]' call, as long as you're inside your while loop. If you want to get details from other tables as well then you'll need to join in your SQL, or do more than one SELECT statement in the same query. If you plan to do more than one select statement, I'd advise you to use the SqlDataAdaptor and DataSet objects to manage your data retrieval as these will make life easier.